# Changing constraints by pressing a button

Tags: swift, uikit

Is there a way to change view’s centerXAnchor constraint to another object (with animation) by pressing a button while the app is running?

Thank's for all of the answers!

Comment: take IBOutlet of  view’s centerXAnchor then change like yourcenterXAnchorOutlet.constant = someValue
yourView.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create an `IBOutlet` for your constraint from the storyboard, something similar to this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And when the button is pressed, you should change the constraint value and update the view layout.

```
centerXConstraint.constant = setYourValueHere
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

If you want to add constraints programmatically, then remove `@IBOutlet weak`.

```
var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Assign your view's center X anchor to it.

```
centerXConstraint = yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: super.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
centerXConstraint.isActive = true
```

after that, you can change it as described above.

Comment: How would I do it programmatically? Where do I "connect" centerXConstraint?

Comment: @VViktor Are you using a storyboard to set your constraints?

Comment: No. I'm doing them programmatically. Really sorry I should've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: No problem, its almost the same, your'e doing something like this for adding your constraint `yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: super.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`, right?

Comment: Yeah, but what about centerXConstraint declared above?

Comment: Change it to `var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!` in your class,
then assign your view's center X anchor to it.
`centerXConstraint = yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: super.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)`
`centerXConstraint.isActive = true`

The other part is the same. Let me know it it works.

Comment: It worked! Thank's I'll mark your answer as the right one then.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the answer and will include programmatically created constraints as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var centerXConstraintOutlet: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClickAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animateViewCenterXConstraint()
    }

    func animateViewCenterXConstraint() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.centerXConstraintOutlet.constant = 30
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question: How do I "connect" centerXConstraintOutlet programmatically?

Comment: you can check this article https://medium.com/@vijay.kharage7/programmatically-animate-using-constraints-d19ce6158cdd

Answer (score 1):

1) Create view’s centerXAnchor constraints related to both the objects.

2) Take outlets of both the constraints.

3) Activate and de-activate them on click of the button as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable for centerXAnchor constraint and assign value on button action. You can try this:

```
var constraintOfCenterXAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
```

in `viewDidLoad()` set `constraintOfCenterXAnchor.constant = 0`

When button pressed, change constraint value and update view

```
constraintOfCenterXAnchor.constant = 30
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 })
```

Comment: How do I assign constraintOfCenterXAnchor to the UIView?

Comment: `constraintOfCenterXAnchor  = yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor) `  and `constraintOfCenterXAnchor.isActive = true`